# Trouble calling a ASP.NET MVC 4 WebApi from a Windows Store Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps

I've got the following code running in a Windows Store application that is *supposed* to call one of my WebApis:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"vinNumber", vinNumber}, 
            {"pictureType", pictureType}, 
            {"blobUri", blobUri}
        };

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    using (HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parms))
    {
        const string url = "http://URL/api/vinbloburis";

        response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    }

    return response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

The WebApi code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string vinNumber, string pictureType, string blobUri)
{
    var vinEntity = new VinEntity
        {
            PartitionKey = vinNumber,
            RowKey = pictureType, 
            BlobUri = blobUri
        };

    _vinRepository.InsertOrUpdate(vinEntity);

    return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent("Success"), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

Using Fiddler, I've observed the following ... here's what the request looks like:

```
POST http://URL/api/vinbloburis HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: URL
Content-Length: 113
Expect: 100-continue

vinNumber=vinNumber&pictureType=top&blobUri=https%3A%2F%2Fmystorage.blob.core.windows.net%2Fimages%2Fimage.png
```

But the response is an error with little/no information:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

I've even tried locally with the debugger attached to the WebApis and my Post method never catches.

Does anyone see something I've missed here? I feel like I'm looking right at it but not seeing it. I should add that I am able to call an HttpGet method while passing a parameter through the querystring. Right now the problem is only with this HttpPost.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Based on some good comments from folks I'm adding some more details.

I have the default routes configured for WebApis ...

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Consequently, I think /URL/api/vinbloburis should work. Additionally, as alluded above, I currently have this working with an HttpGet. Here's what's working in the Windows Store app to call the HttpGet WebApi ...

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var sasUrl = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            sasUrl = sasUrl.Trim('"');

            return sasUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

... and it's calling the following WebApi ...

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string blobName)
{
    const string containerName = "images";
    const string containerPolicyName = "policyname";

    _helper.SetContainerPolicy(containerName, containerPolicyName);

    string sas = _helper.GenerateSharedAccessSignature(blobName, containerName, containerPolicyName);

    return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(sas),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
}
```

I hope the additional information helps!

Comment: Just to confirm - have you changed the name of the method you are calling? Currently your code sample has a method name of POST but your HTTP request is trying to call vinbloburis ? This would cause the error you see.

Comment: If you do the POST from fiddler, does it work?

Comment: Have you tried using PostJsonAsync? Can you please share your routing config?

Comment: These are great questions, folks! @LewisBenge, I don't think that's the issue - I've shared how the WebApis are registered and some additional info related to the HttpGet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code, as is and I was getting a 404 error.

I changed the signature to

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(FormDataCollection data)
```

and it worked.

You can also just do this,

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(VinEntity vinEntity)
```

and the model binder will do the mapping work for you.

Rick Strahl has a post on the issue here http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API

Comment: I suspect you're on to something here. However, I've tried to make both changes and still I get the same error response and my method isn't called. I'll keep digging into this ...

Comment: @wade  Plug this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api tracewriter into your config.  IT will show you exactly what is causing the error.

Comment: Okay, as is so often the case, the problem is an unrelated issue that caused the HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. I use Ninject and it turns out that one of my bindings was causing the constructor to throw an exception. Once I resolved your suggestion Post(VinEntity vinEntity) worked perfect and was a simple solution. I'll try to update my primary post with some more information once I resolve. TX!

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on Internet Networking in your manifest?

Comment: Yes - both **Internet (Client)** and **Internet (Client & Server)** are turned on (although I think I only need Client). I should have added that I have another service I'm calling successfully but the difference is that it's an HttpGet and the parameter is passed int he querystring. Right now I'm just struggling to call the HttpPost. TX!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a Cross Domain Ajax Security issue. See JSONP info here. => http://json-p.org/

Comment: He is making the call from a Windows Store app.  There are no cross domain issues with Windows Clients.